# How do I Attach a Rigid Body to a Bone?

Tags: animation, physics, bones, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to make rigid body physics interact with an (Armature-)animated character.

For starters, I created a short piece of chain falling onto an animated box. The chain consists of 5 individual rigid bodies, the animated box also is a rigid body with the 'Animated' property set. When the animated box moves, I expect the chain to react to this.

[image: Chain Resting on Thin Air]

As you can see, what I get instead is that the chain rests on the original pose of the animated box (as if it was static), even though it has moved out of the way.

- The animated box is of type 'Active', set to 'Animated' and 'Dynamic', rigid body deactivation is turned off.
- The chain links are the same, except they're not set to 'Animated'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using the armature-driven mesh to interact in a rigid body world, you need to toggle the **Deforming** in the settings for that animated box.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for the elaborate screenshot :)  However, my Blender 2.69 seems to be missing that very option. Here's what I see in my properties panel when I select the animated box mesh: http://i.imgur.com/iB9IOPm.png.

Comment: Ah, right. Actually it is in the development version, you can download the daily builds [here](http://builder.blender.org/download/). It will be with the coming 2.70. See [here](https://developer.blender.org/rB2260a7d) and [here](https://developer.blender.org/rBceb2430).

Comment: Lately, there is a nice tutorial in CGCookie.com to show you how to do the similar thing without this new feature. See [here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/creating-ragdoll-rigs/). It is a bit complex, but probably works to you.