# Cell Fracture not working when model hits it (Blender Internal)

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to animate Godzilla's tail tip hitting a building. I have a cube and used cell fracture, set it to active, then checked the enable deactivation and start deactivated box and clicked copy from active.
I then clicked the Godzilla mesh and set it to passive and checked animated. the ground and everything else is just passive. I even inserted keyframes on the godzilla mesh (clicking I 3 times and selecting location rotation and scale) and it worked, but when I rendered it his tail goes through the building. Please help me quickly and explain thoroughly what I did wrong and what needs to be done.

[image]

Comment: Godzilla's settings should be Active and Animated (without Dynamic and Deactivation off) but... There is something wrong with the Godzilla's mesh and I can't find what it is. When I hit the wall with simple Sphere it works ok.

Comment: Oh man. Do you think there's others that could help me? Thanks so much for your help too.

Comment: Probably yes. Just wait. I'm still trying to figure it out. I've found that Godzillas body works ok, there is something with his tail.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8HqdmH29VA You can see I tested it there with a similar model and it worked fine. I used MMD tools to import the model in the current animation, if that helps.

Comment: I'm closer, this has connection with armature. Give me couple more minutes.

Comment: Look at this one: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/how-do-i-attach-a-rigid-body-to-a-bone

Comment: So have you found the answer yet? Or was it in that link?

Comment: Look at this: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1853/ I've deleted armature, animation and everything I've found, I've added very simple armature and it's working just fine. So I narrow this problem strictly to armature setup.

Comment: One more thing. I've wrong names of vertex groups in the file. They are all just squares instead of names. Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: Yeah the squares are because the person who made the model was Japanese. If I renamed some of the vertex groups do you think that will do the trick?

Comment: Many of them are the same so I think it could help. As you can see in blend file I've posted everything is ok without vertex groups.